# Unexpected ST_DWithin result when using geography

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type, st-dwithin

This query:

```
SELECT ST_DWithin(
  ST_Buffer('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(7.1670005 45.9968257,7.1670216 45.9969537,7.1670216 45.9971326, 7.1670484 45.9972789, 7.1671905 45.9974074, 7.1672844 45.9974801, 7.1659165 46.0005209, 7.1653103 46.0010221, 7.1652359 46.0013015)'::geography, 1.0),
  'SRID=4326;POINT(7.1672844 45.9974801)'::geography,
  0.0
);
```

Returns `FALSE`. Note that the point that is passed as the second parameter to `ST_DWithin` is part of the `LINESTRING` passed in the first parameter, so I expect it to return `TRUE`.

When removing the first or last point from the `LINESTRING`, then it correctly returns `TRUE`.

When using `geometry` instead of `geography` and using 0.0000105 for the buffer (which is roughly 1 meter at that latitude), then it correctly returns `TRUE`.

Could somebody comment on this and let me know why this would happen (if not a bug)?

Comment: I think that the result is unexpected. Also the distance between the buffered geometry and reference point `SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_Buffer('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(7.1670005 45.9968257,7.1670216 45.9969537,7.1670216 45.9971326, 7.1670484 45.9972789, 7.1671905 45.9974074, 7.1672844 45.9974801, 7.1659165 46.0005209, 7.1653103 46.0010221, 7.1652359 46.0013015)'::geography, 1.0),
  'SRID=4326;POINT(7.1672844 45.9974801)'::geography
);` that is `0.99478251`. I would write mail to postgis-users list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/postgis-users/.